# Why can't I center my menubar?

Tags: html, css, position, center, menubar

I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS. I'm making a menu bar horizontal and I can't seem to align it to center of screen. I have tried `margin:0 auto;` and `<body align=center>` but neither seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

#menu {
margin:0 auto;
float:left;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
border-top:1 solid #ccc;
border-left:1 solid #ccc;
border-bottom:1 solid #ccc;
}

#menu li {
float:left;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
}

#menu li a {
display:block;
padding:10px 80px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#069;
border-right:1px solid #ccc;
font-weight:bold;
}   

#menu li a:hover {
color:#c00;
background-color:#fff;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I'm using `margin:0 auto;`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What browsers have you tried? Is is only not work in IE, Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `float` elements. Floating elements will not follow that centering unless your container is treated as a block, or inline block.

To reach the desired result, you'd want to do something like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9Wcn/).

By adding a container, center margin and using `display: inline-block` on the `#menu` they will be centered like normal content. Note that this might not work in IE, in which case, you should add a line with `*display: inline;`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9Wcn/) | Code

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    border-top:1 solid #ccc;
    border-left:1 solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:1 solid #ccc;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}

#menu li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#069;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    font-weight:bold;
}   

#menu li a:hover {
    color:#c00;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your menu a width if you want to center it inside it's parent element (in this case, the body.) Additionally, remove your float - it's not going to center if you're floating it one direction or another.

Comment: thank you i didn't know i had to center the whole body. as i said before I'm new to HTML and CSS. ;)

Comment: @Arbitur See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the menu a width `width: 400px;` or what your desired width is.  Then, you can set the left and right margin to auto `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a width to your `menu` and remove `float:left`

eg.

```
#menu {
margin:0 auto;    
list-style:none;
padding:0;
border-top:1 solid #ccc;
border-left:1 solid #ccc;
border-bottom:1 solid #ccc;
width:900px;
display:block;
}
```

Comment: This will not center the content due to the fact that the content (the `li`s) is also floating.